Can tab_model collapse all models in one column?
I am using the tab_model function from the sjPlot package in R to do a table with 18 univariate models, all with the same response variable, but with one different variable each, as an example, this could be the first two models:
GEE1  <- geeglm(hospitalization ~ xxx,                   
    id = record_id, data = dades, family = binomial, corstr = "ar1")
GEE2  <- geeglm(hospitalization ~ xxx,                 
    id = record_id, data = dades, family = binomial, corstr = "ar1")

When using tab_model, I am getting one column (or set of columns) for each model, I would like to have them all in the same set of columns . Meaning just one column for all the estimates, all the p-values etc. But now I have one set (estimates, 95% and p-value) of columns per each model. making the table, obviously too wide. I want to have just all the models listed with the results.
I have tried to do a function and use kable, but it is very manual and I would love to find an alternative
A dummie example could be:
data = mtcars
m1 = lm(mpg~ disp, data = data)
m2 = lm(mpg~ cyl, data = data)
library(sjPlot)
tab_model(m1,m2,show.intercept = FALSE)

If I run this I get a table somewhat similar to:





mpg



mpg




Predictors
Estimates
$C I$
$p$
Estimates
$C I$
$p$


disp
-0.04
$-0.05--0.03$
$<0.001$





cy1



-2.88
$-3.53--2.22$
$<0.001$



I would need to collapse all in one column as I am fitting this for 18 variables (I need that to do a model selection with Hosmer-Lemeshow algoritm due to the structure of my data).
It has to be something like:





mpg





Predictors
Estimates
$C I$
$p$


disp
-0.04
$-0.05--0.03$
$<0.001$


cy1
-2.88
$-3.53--2.22$
$<0.001$



And then I wil export it to latex, tat culd be another question but if you know the answer drop it here too :)

Could you please share some reproducible data using dput?

@Quinten I have added an example and a visual of what I want! Thanks
